# How to prove this tedious (but easy) derivative theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, derivatives

I'm reading [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) (page 3) and I'm having problems with (4), (5) and (6) part of this theorem.

[image]

This proof seems really easy to demonstrate, but there are a lot of calculations. Is there some strategy to prove this theorem without tedious and tiresome computations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property $(1)$ allows us to consider $F$ a monomial of (total) degree $m$, say $$F(X_1,\dots,X_n)=X_1^{j_1}\cdots X_n^{j_n}$$ with $j_1+\cdots+j_n=m$. Then $F_{X_i}=j_iX_1^{j_1}\cdots X_i^{j_i-1}\cdots X_n^{j_n}$ (or $0$ if $j_i=0$). Then $X_iF_{X_i}=j_iF$ and now sum these up.

Comment: I'm trying to prove the case $n=2$. When we sum, we have $X_1F_{X_1}+X_2F_{X_2}=(j_1+j_2)F$. After I tried to take the derivative both sides, I couldn't take the equality in (4).

Comment: For example $(G_1F_{X_1}(G_1,G_2))'=G_1'F_{X_1}(G_1,G_2)+G_1\big(F_{X_1}(G_1,G_2)\big)_X$, right?

Comment: @user42912 I don't understand what are you trying to show. Do you want to prove (4)?

Comment: yes, I'm trying to show (4), but I think I'm doing something wrong. I don't know why.

Comment: You could ask this as a new question. This way you can explain better what troubles you.